# What browser or bot has the user agent of "SD-1.30.1"?

Tags: browsers, user-agent

I have tried checking on Google but to no avail. Does anyone recognize this user agent?

Answer (score 1):

The [User-Agent](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.43) header is supplied by the client and, as may be the case with popular browsers like [FireFox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/user-agent-switcher/), automated HTTP tools like [wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/HTTP-Options.html#index-user_002dagent-98), and [robots](http://support.free-conversant.com/2701), (particularly malicious bots) the information in the user-agent header may be misreported or nonsensical to all but whomever set it.